Only 'Users and Access' Visible on App Store Connect – Apps Not Showing
I’m facing an issue with my App Store Connect account where only the "Users and Access" section is visible. All of my apps are not showing up, and I cannot access the usual sections like "My Apps," "App Analytics," or "Sales and Trends." I've tried the following troubleshooting steps without success:
Logged out and back into my account
Cleared browser cache and cookies
Tried accessing the platform from different browsers and devices
I also double-checked my account permissions, and everything seems to be in order. The issue appears to be limited to the App Store Connect interface itself, as the "Users and Access" section is the only one that loads properly.
Has anyone else experienced this, or does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve it? Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Why can't I ask customer service questions?
